# How Can I assert the value of "Deleted" flag in Json response in a list for a specific Id ?

Tags: soapui, assertions

I am trying to assert whether an item has been deleted successfully. I have a delete end point and i got success code. in other API I can get a list of all existing Items. how can I assert the Deleted flag value only for my deleted item.I have the Id can check if Id is equal to what I have deleted then assert delete=True. but I don't know how write the script assertion for that.
many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hi Guys I sorted it out! it's the solution here.it may help someone:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
def slurper = new JsonSlurper();
def response = messageExchange.response.responseContent;
def parsedJson = slurper.parseText(response);
def i=0;
```

//retrieveing the values of testSuite properties

```
def tcChecklistId = 
messageExchange.modelItem.testCase.testSuite.getPropertyValue("Id");
log.info(tcChecklistId);
```

//looping through each of the objects returned in the JSON response

```
for( i=0; i<parsedJson.size;i++)
{
```

//checking if the physicalId of the JSON response object equals the user defined physicalId value

```
if(parsedJson[i].checklistId == tcChecklistId.toInteger())
{
 assert parsedJson[i].deleted == true , "Item has been deleted 
successfully!";
break;
}
}
```